# what's the name of this binary tree structure?

Tags: data-structures

I am trying to implement the following data structure by js, but I was wondering if anyone knows the name of such binary tree? thanks.

[image]

It is a full binary tree T of unlimited height. Suppose root is at level 0.

From level 1, the number of nodes at level i and level i+1 are both 2^i,
where i is in {1, 2, 3,...}.

The left subtree of any node is complete.
As shown in Figure, denote the right most node in each
level i  which is in {0, 1, 2,...} as v_i, then the left
subtree of each node v_i is a perfect binary tree, denoted as T_i.

Suppose the leaf nodes in T_i have height zero, then each subtree T_i
is of height i and has 2^i leaves.

Comment: What are the rules for its construction?

Comment: @BoristheSpider thanks, pls see my updates

Comment: I’ve never seen a tree like this before. What’s the context in which it arose?